# Cannot require node_modules in electron worker process

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, web-worker

### Question

I'm trying to use web workers in electron. So far I'm able to instanciate the worker process from the renderer process, but when I try to do a `require('some_module')` in the worker process the process crashes with the error.

> *Cannot find module 'some_module'*.

The cjs loader cannot find my module apparently. But when I make the same `require` call from the renderer process, I'm able to `require` the module.

I've followed all the steps mentioned [here](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/multithreading). Also I've set the option`nodeIntegrationInWorker: true` and I can make `require` calls to node inbuilt modules like `fs` with no problems.

---

### A few observations

1. `__dirname` in the rendered process resolves to

   > *root/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/electron.asar/renderer*

   and in the worker process resolves to

   > *root/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/electron.asar/worker*

   as far as I've done the reading the require function should be able to find my module in the **node_modules** dir which is parent to both the **renderer** and **worker** dir
2. A quick look at the `process` global in the worker reveals that `process.type` is equals `worker` while `process.argv[1]` is equals `--type=renderer` which I find strange.

---

***Meta*:**
Electron version = "4.0.0", platform = "win32", arch = "x64", node version = "v10.11.0"

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: Having the same issue. Electron is awful. Very poor documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. As a workaround, I use this.

```
    const paths = [
        path.join(process.resourcesPath, 'app.asar', 'node_modules'),
        path.join(process.resourcesPath, 'app', 'node_modules'),//when asar is disabled
        process.resourcesPath.replace(/electron[\\/]dist[\\/]resources/g, '')
    ];

    paths.map((path) => {
        global.require.main.paths.push(path);
    });
```

The above snippet manually adds the paths node looks to resolve the required module.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do the above. Just do a require from app.asar's node_modules:

```js
   const myModule = require(process.resourcesPath + '/app.asar/node_modules/' + 'modulename');
```

Thank me later ;