# Cannot require nodejs files in electron worker process

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, web-worker

I am running a worker on a page of electron after a `button` click which runs the beginning part of the file just fine. But it gives me the error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:940 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './bar'
Require stack:
- electron/js2c/worker_init
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:940:15)
    at o._resolveFilename (node:electron/js2c/worker_init:33:1095)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:785:27)
    at c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13343)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at 3a43803….js:21:5
```

`foo.js` is in the same directory as `bar.js` which is being run as a worker.

I checked the location of the directory and it shows:

> C:\Users\programmer\project\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\worker

I expect the locaction to be:

> C:\Users\programmer\project\dist\src

P.S. I researched further and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54414691/cannot-require-node-modules-in-electron-worker-process) but the solution for it did not work for me despite being my exact problem.